# How to read spec characters as a string for argv

Tags: terminal, argv

My program stops reading arguments I gave it via terminal after encountering a # symbol.

For exemple when i execute it with

> ./myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3 ## arg4 arg5 arg6

My argc is 4 (program name + 1st three arguments) but my program don't see any arguments after the `##` (it works when i add quotes but i HAVE to make it without).

Any ideas on how to make my program see it as a string?

Comment: and where is your program ??

Comment: What command shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your shell is interpreting the `#` character as the start of a comment and ignoring everything after that.  You can either escape the `#` by putting a `\` before it, or put the entire argument in single quotes.

```
./myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3 \#\# arg4 arg5 arg6
```

or

```
./myprogram arg1 arg2 arg3 '##' arg4 arg5 arg6
```

Your program will see both these inputs in the same way - the argument will be `##`.

Comment: Ye, it works with `\#\#` or `'##'` but i have to do it without.

Comment: You'll either need a different shell or see if your shell has some other way to avoid interpreting the `#` as a comment.